# PDB does not match image Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm trying to make a few additions to an open source project, npp-community, but can't seem to debug.  The code that I'm trying to debug is compiled into a dll then linked to the primary project.  When setting breakpoints I get the following error :

> the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

When I check the modules under `debug>windows>modules` I check symbol load information and get the following error.

> PDB does not match image

I have tried exiting visual studio and restarting/recompiling but that does not seem to fix anything.  Google seems to give threads that go in circles and no clear answers.

Answer (score 10):

i have a similar issue with my VS2010 project, turn out the issue is due to mistmatch of **Project properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Output Files** -> *'Program Database File name'*, and **Project properties** -> **Linker** -> **Debugging** -> *'Generate Program Database File'*.

Fixed it by change the *'Program Database File name'* to "inherit from parent or project default".

Comment: This helped, thanks. In my case I had to set it to _my_pyd_name_d.pdb .

Comment: Oh, and restarting Visual helped a lot, too.

Comment: Boy that's annoying that the same setting is in two places - and they must be manually kept in sync.  If they are out of sync, there's no warning.  Worse, your PDB won't load inexplicably.

Comment: Thanks a million times, this solved the same damn problem I was having!

Comment: This is helpful and for my case I also need to set ' Project properties -> Linker -> OutputFile' to 'inherit from parent or project default'. Both need to be fixed I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here lies in the fact that the debugger was unable to find a valid PDB files for your modules. PDB files are matched against binary images using two parameters: identifier (GUID) and age. There is more information about this process in [this article](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debuginfomatch.html).

Make sure that you have valid PDB files for your modules and that they are in the same directory as modules or in the debugger's search path (Debug->Options and settings...->Symbols).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens because you might have build the project as a release.

Right click on the solution and click on "Batch Build" > Check all your projects and click "Clean"

Answer (score 1):

I had a name clash with a nuget package. I was using the googletest package in a project that was called gtest. Visual Studio did not like that and couldn't find the pdb files. Renamed the project and then it worked.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. Why does this cause a clash?

Comment: I honestly don't know the reason (anymore), just that you should probably try a different name for you project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this while working on a Smart Device project for WinCE5.0. The solution was to cold boot the device I was debugging on + clean the solution in vs2008

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging something that is a nuget package I recommend this:

Go in `Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols` and add `https://symbols.nuget.org/download/symbols`

Otherwise well, you are left with manually modifying guid from dll to match that in PDB file.